# Change value for a range of cells

Tags: vba, excel

The code should check if the cells in column E have a value of "J".

If so, paste the value "positiv" into the cell of column N of each respective line.

I tried several methods including range, cells and so on but I always get a runtime error.

```vb
With wsDURATION
    
    Range("A1").Select
    
    For x = 1 To wsDURLrow Step 1
        If Cells.Offset(x, 4).Value = "J" Then
            Cells.Offset(x, 13).Value = "positiv"
        End If
    Next x
    
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I have figured it out and the topic may be closed :)

```
With wsDURATION

For Each cell In rng.Cells
    x = 0
    If cell.Value = "J" Then
        cell.Offset(x, 9).Value = "positiv"
    End If
    x = x + 1
Next
End With
```